# How convert JSON formated QString to an array

Tags: qt, qstring

I'm using QT 4.8 and MinGW 4.8 and my JSON formated QString looks like:

> {"name":"Adam","body":"is fat","Eyes":"blue"}

How to convert this string to something like that:

> array[name] = Adam
>
> array[body] = is fat

or

> array[0] = Adam
>
> array[1] = is fat...

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Is it a JSON string?

Comment: can't you upgrade to Qt 5.0? it has native JSON support witch makes it pretty easy, if not maybe use some external c++ JSON lib to parse the input. Of course you can parse the string yourself, but why...

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Qt 5.0+ you might use the native JSON support of Qt core.

E.g. with your input

```
QString s(R"({"name":"Adam","body":"is fat","Eyes":"blue"})"); // raw string
QJsonDocument json = QJsonDocument::fromJson(s.toUtf8());
QJsonObject obj = json.object(); // since your string is an JSON object
QString name = obj.value("name").toString(); // Adam
QString body = obj.value("body").toString(); // is fat
QString eyes = obj.value("Eyes").toString(); // blue
```

You can also read all the keys with `QStringList keys = obj.keys();` or whatever you like, check the Qt doc for more info: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#details

Answer (score 0):

In Qt 4.8 you can start with getting rid of the {} brackets and quotes by using the [QString::remove()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#remove-2) function. Then you can continue with the [QString::split()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#split) function to separate the items.

```
QStringList results;
QString str = "{\"name\":\"Adam\",\"body\":\"is fat\",\"Eyes\":\"blue\"}";    
str.remove(QChar('{')); // remove the '{' character
str.remove(QChar('}')); // remove the '}' character
str.remove(QChar('\"')); // remove the '"' character
QStringList pairs = str.split(","); // separate by comma
//
for (int i = 0; i < str.count(); i++)
{
  QStringList pairItems = pairs[i].split(":");
  results.append(pairItems[1]);
}
```

In this case, the QStringList "results" would look like: results[ 0 ] = "Adam", results[ 1 ] = "is fat" and so on...

This is one of the options you have. Of course there are more elegant solutions but this one is quite simple. I hope it helps you.

**Edit:** Also keep in mind that this solution will not help you with some complex JSON output. In that case you should use some of the other options proposed.

Comment: This solution satisfies me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Another similar solution would be to use `QString::split` with  a regular expression. In this case it would be only one command.

Comment: This solution does not cover nested objects. I would prefer using some 3rd party C library for JSON parsing. See the list at http://www.json.org

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to parse [JSON](http://www.json.org) format. I see from other answers that native JSON parsing is not supported in Qt 4.8 you are using, so you should be able to use any C library that is listed on http://www.json.org for JSON format parsing.